# How to use my domain as a extension

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, domain-name-system, domain

I have a domain, let's say `example.com`

I know that it is possible to use `example.com` as a *"extension"*. I know I am using the wrong term, but I don't know the technical term.

What I means is, having something like `site.example.com` and `another.example.com`

I have a `Ubuntu 16` machine running `nginx`, serving content at `example.com`.

How can I make this machine serve one content at `site.example.com` and another at `another.example.com`?

Thank you!

Comment: Create new `server` blocks for each hostname.

Comment: Like server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.example.com; } ?

Comment: The technical term would be "subdomain".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's say you have a domain, `example.com`

You presumably have paid to control the domain (register it) and to associate the domain name with an IP address (DNS service).  Quite likely you are using the same company for both.

The company that you pay for DNS service, also most likely will provide DNS service for at least other hosts within your domain (`site.example.com`, `another.example.com`) and probably sub-domains (another topic).  You can review their site for help setting up your DNS "zone" or "records".

If you are using one server to host different content for multiple host names, the first step is to configure the additional hosts to associate the other host names (e.g. `site.example.com`) with the same IP address associated with `example.com`.

The second step is to configure your web server.  This article addresses that challenge in some detail: https://superuser.com/questions/841910/host-multiple-website-using-nginx-on-the-same-ip#841920

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are basically wanting other hostnames to be valid in your DNS zone (domain) and then once you have DNS working for the other names you'll want to set up a new name based host (Apache term) or a new server definition (nginx)